# taverna = rustic underground kitchen or dining area?

Tags: word-meaning

Can [*taverna*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/taverna) mean a rustic, brick, underground kitchen or dining area?

Comment: What isn't clear in the dictionary definition you're linking to?

Comment: @DaG Somewhat: "_a volte di lusso, arredati in stile rustico_", but luxurious and rustic seem mutually exclusive, but I suppose "hole in the wall" places can have very good food.

Comment: 'Arredato in stile rustico' doesn't necessarily mean 'not expensive, poor',  it is a furnishing style, it means 'country-style furnishing', and can also be expensive  or 'country -chic'.

Comment: OP, check the definition of _rustico_ in the same dictionary: as you'll see, and @BakerStreet explains, it's (also) a particular style, not necessarily a degree of richness or refinement.